# focus Javascript no me funciona

Tags: javascript

por que no funciona focus() ??
este es el código...

```js
var pcart =document.getElementById('pcart');
if ((parseInt(pcart.value)) != 100){
      pcart.focus();
      alert ("debe valer 100");
      return false;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pcart" name="cartones"/>
```

Comment: En que Evento se debe ejecutar?, DIgamos cuando el id="pcart" pierde el foco? cuando cambia su valor? en el Submit?

Comment: Cuidado con parseInt. Si el usuario ingresa un 0 parseInt considera el texto en OCTAL. parseInt("010") = 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontré la solucion! jeje

setTimeout(function(){pcart.focus();}, 1);

Quedaria asi:

```js
var pcart =document.getElementById('pcart');
if ((parseInt(pcart.value)) != 100){
      alert ("debe valer 100");
      setTimeout(function(){pcart.focus();}, 1);    
      return false;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pcart" name="cartones"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltaría el Evento en cual se debe ejecutar el If y luego el focus. Yo lo hice con un boton de modo de ejemplo.

```js
function Focus(){
var pcart =document.getElementById('pcart');
if ((parseInt(pcart.value)) != 100){
      pcart.focus();
      alert ("debe valer 100");
      return false;}};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pcart" name="cartones"/>
<input type="button" id="pcart" value="Clik Para evento" onclick="Focus()" name="cartones"/>
```

Comment: Claro, lo ejecuto en el onsubmit del form, el alert me funciona bien, pero no me va el focus

Comment: Podrías editar la pregunta y poner el código completo. Osea, con el evento onSubmit y dentro de este el código

Answer (score 1):

Lo correcto (si fuera una validación) sería ponerlo en el evento blur:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    pcart.addEventListener('blur', function(){
         if(parseInt(this.value,10) != 100){
             alert("debe valer 100");
             this.focus();
         }
    });
});
```

Esto igual tiene algunos problemas, y es que si el usuario no va a poder abandonar la página sin cambiar el valor (o no de forma natural).

Lo ideal sería poner un texto al lado y solo hacer foco la primera vez o si el valor cambió. Hay que prestar atención a la experiencia de usuario.